# How to force docker-compose to use specific port

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose

Hey I don't know if the title is right, but I'm working on my project. Tools that I use are symfony and docker. When I start pgsql database on my other machines, they're using port `5432`, but I just installed fresh linux on my new computer and it uses port `49153` it took me quiet some time to figure out that the port was the problem. Same thing happens if I start new project don't change anything and pg database still runs on port `49153`, it's a bit annoying while working on few machines. So is it possible to force docker to setup database on port `5432` for all of my future projects or everytime I have to change port in .env file?

My docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-14}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
```

.env file

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=14&charset=utf8"
```

Comment: Do you specify `ports:` for your database, so it can be reached from the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exemple if you want to map your pgsql database :
From the local docker container port 5432
To your local env 5432 port.

Add

```
 ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

I forgot which one is the container and which one is the local but you will find out pretty easier now.

```
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-14}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: Thank you. Additional question: is it possible to set default port in my docker so it'll be ```5432``` so I don't have to specify this port everytime?

Comment: This is exactly what it does or i did not understand your question, what do u mean ?

Comment: the port is inside the docker container - if you want to access it from your localhost you need the port mapping.